# How to print the array of elements in Angular 12 and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I am not able to display the array of elements values in html page.

I have selected values of json array of object, from this result I removed the duplicate category values, and that values convered to array of string. and I listed that array of element. But I don't know to display the forEach element in a ngFor loop in angular.

```
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {
public menus : any = [];
newuniq: any[][];

ngOnInit() {
 this.newmenuService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(resp=>{
      this.menus = resp;
    console.log("cart",this.menus)
    })
 const newuniq = [...new Set(this.menus.map(item => item.category
      ))];

 newuniq.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log("element",element);
      
    });

}
```

component.html
 `{{newuniq}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How to display data from an array of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063766/angular-how-to-display-data-from-an-array-of-an-array)

Comment: I don't understand, you did the most difficult part. Did you try something like `<div *ngFor="let menu of newuniq">{{menu.category}}</div>`  Can you be more specific about where you are stuck ?

Comment: Normally, you should be able to display an array like this `<div *ngFor="let n of newuniq">{{n}}</div>` (but you also have to set this.newuniq = newuniq; in your .ts file)

Comment: @CodeSpirit yes, that is my question

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of newuniq">
{{item.category}}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this @vahidmehrjooei but not working.

Comment: Could you add here your object?